# How do I make take an object out of a vector as it's original class?

Tags: java, object, vector

In my program I have a class called Circles and a class called CircleList which is a vector of Circles.

I can add and take away Circles to the list fine but when I try to use a circle from the list like so.

```
Circle test = CircleList.elementAt(0);
```

It fails as a Circle is expected but an object is found. Is there anyway I can fix this so it comes out of the vector back as a Circle rather than as an Object?

here is the start of the CircleList class with the constructor

```
import java.util.Vector;
public class CircleList
{
    private Vector CircleList;

    public CircleList()
    {
    CircleList = new Vector();
    }
```

Comment: How is your `CircleList` declared?

Comment: I'm sorry could you explain, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Is `CircleList` a class that you wrote (as you claim), or an object of type `Vector`?

Comment: Basically show us your `CircleList` code.

Comment: Show us the code for CircleList, especially it's definition. Does it extend List? Vector? What generic does it declare?

Comment: Show more code please.

Comment: It seems you've learnt Java with a book or teacher which hasn't changed/who hasn't learnt anything since Java 1.1. We're at Java 7. Don't use Vector anymore. And use generic types.

Comment: I think CircleList is a variable. He is just not following the naming conventions ;)

Comment: @EdgarBoda I agree that it's probably a variable, but he claimed it to be a class.  If it's a class, then he's probably simply got a problem with his `elementAt` method.

Comment: OP said it's a vector of circles.  The question is whether they declared it as `Vector` or as `Vector<Circle>`.  Almost certainly, the problem is that they wrote `Vector`, and they could fix the code by writing `Vector<Circle>` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it like this

```
public class CircleList {
    private Vector<Circle> circleList;

    public CircleList() {
        circleList = new Vector<Circle>();
    }
```

If you do this, the compiler knows that you'll only use `circleList` for storing `Circle` objects, not some other kind of object, and will therefore allow you to refer to anything that comes out of `circleList` with a `Circle` variable.

You might also consider using `ArrayList` in place of `Vector`.  The `Vector` class does some additional synchronisation which you almost certainly don't need.  For more details on this particular type of synchronisation and why you don't want it, I would suggest reading Jon Skeet's answer to [Why is Java Vector class considered obsolete or deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated)

Comment: Thankyou, this was really helpful. I'd also like to mention I would be using arraylists where possible but the exercise on my course asked to use a vector which is why I did. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem is occuring when you are defining vector.

Please share the insertion code.

However first try below code snippet for inserting elements into vector.

```
 Vector<Circle> CircleList = new Vector<Circle>(50); 
 CircleList.add(circle1);
 CircleList.add(circle2);
 ........................
```

Then retrieve the element.

```
Circle test = CircleList.elementAt(0);
```